# Using hadoop on AWS to proccess image files

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

So, I have this work to do: "From an images dataset located on S3, use Elastic Map Reduce (EMR) to convert the images into grayscale and write them all into a PDF file".

Since then, I was looking for the ways to do it and I figured out that Hadoop doesn't have a default image file input format. So I found two methods:

- [Converting the image files to Sequence File](https://github.com/cpatrick/kwmapreduce/blob/master/wip/bintoseq/src/BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFile.java)
- [Using hibImport](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/examples/hibImport.html)

**Problem:**

I try both methods, but I couldn't have what I wanted because I got errors on both tries.

For the first method I got this:

```
2016-06-22 11:54:34,894 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy (main): Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-2-62.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.2.62:8032
2016-06-22 11:54:39,387 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat (main): Total input paths to process : 170
2016-06-22 11:54:39,494 INFO com.hadoop.compression.lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader (main): Loaded native gpl library
2016-06-22 11:54:39,508 INFO com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec (main): Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev 3454067872d644fcdf99dbacccc3e0acfcd41bc0]
2016-06-22 11:54:39,740 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter (main): number of splits:170
2016-06-22 11:54:40,366 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter (main): Submitting tokens for job: job_1466077468134_0004
2016-06-22 11:54:40,767 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl (main): Submitted application application_1466077468134_0004
2016-06-22 11:54:40,970 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): The url to track the job: http://ip-172-31-2-62.us-west-2.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_1466077468134_0004/
2016-06-22 11:54:40,971 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Running job: job_1466077468134_0004
2016-06-22 11:55:00,456 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Job job_1466077468134_0004 running in uber mode : false
2016-06-22 11:55:00,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 0% reduce 0%
2016-06-22 11:55:17,726 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 1% reduce 0%
2016-06-22 11:55:17,745 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1466077468134_0004_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
2016-06-22 11:55:18,783 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 0% reduce 0%
2016-06-22 11:55:31,906 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1466077468134_0004_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
2016-06-22 11:55:31,908 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1466077468134_0004_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
2016-06-22 11:55:33,932 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1466077468134_0004_m_000003_0, Status : FAILED
2016-06-22 11:55:49,079 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1466077468134_0004_m_000002_1, Status : FAILED
2016-06-22 11:55:59,166 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1466077468134_0004_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
2016-06-22 11:56:01,184 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1466077468134_0004_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
2016-06-22 11:56:04,209 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1466077468134_0004_m_000003_1, Status : FAILED
2016-06-22 11:56:19,372 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1466077468134_0004_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
2016-06-22 11:56:27,438 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1466077468134_0004_m_000002_2, Status : FAILED
2016-06-22 11:56:29,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1466077468134_0004_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
2016-06-22 11:56:34,497 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1466077468134_0004_m_000003_2, Status : FAILED
2016-06-22 11:56:49,613 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 2% reduce 0%
2016-06-22 11:56:50,620 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 100%
2016-06-22 11:56:51,644 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Job job_1466077468134_0004 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1466077468134_0004_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

2016-06-22 11:56:51,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Counters: 17
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=13
        Killed map tasks=169
        Killed reduce tasks=3
        Launched map tasks=15
        Other local map tasks=11
        Data-local map tasks=4
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=7254456
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=302269
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=0
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=302269
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=232142592
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
```

For the second method I just got this (it's like if it didn't find the path):

```
Input image directory: s3://tarefahadoop/input
Input FS: local FS
Output HIB: s3://tarefahadoop/images.hib
Overwrite HIB if it exists: false
```

For me, the best solution would be to convert the files to SequenceFile, since I already have the part 2 of the work I have to do (open SequenceFile, convert to image, convert the image to grayscale (map) and write on pdf (reduce)). But I appreciate any other idea that could work.

Comment: What is your data size? What kind of Images? Environment you are using on Amazon EMR? Any other technologies you've tried with Amazon?

Comment: Hi, It is a homework in a subject of my masters..I've used some Amazon services, such as EC2, S3, Load Balancing, etc. I realized that if I try to load an EC2 instance, install hadoop on it and try to execute my code it works! Now I see that the problem may be with EMR.

My dataset has approx 300 images with 1MB each (it's just for testing)

Comment: Ok, As I can see the part which you're doing to do hibimport is right. Now while processing on EMR with your Hadoop job is somewhere going faulty. Can you check the logs for the Mappers/Reducers failed and paste it here for more clearance. Thanks